# undefined local variable or method `http' for main:Object Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, net-http

I have a header and url as specified below:

```
header = { 'User-Agent' => 'SubDB/1.0 (Subtitle-Downloader /1.0; https://github.com/gautamsawhney/Subtitle-Downloader)' }
url = "http://sandbox.thesubdb.com/?action=download&hash=" + hash + "&language=en"
```

I am try to send an `HTTP` get request using 
`send_request` method in ruby. I am basically trying to access the SubDB API. I have written the following code to send a request :

```
res = http.send_request('GET', url, header)
puts res.body
```

I have also done this `require net/http` , but I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `http' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong and if can I use any other method for the same? The inclusion of the header is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, You need to instantiate the Net::Http before using that

```
   http = Net::HTTP.new "sandbox.thesubdb.com"
   res = http.send_request("GET", "/?action=download....", nil, headers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much but can you explain me the reason for doing what you did?

Comment: @gautam I didnt use in my projects., Just trying to answer your question and get some points. ;)